# How do I get result from SELECT clause after CREATE and INSERT clause?

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I have a query that I intend to put into a stored procedure for ultimate use in Tableau. I am getting affected row(s) instead of the grid result.

The query is as follows:

```
IF EXISTS #A DUMP #A
CREATE #A
INSERT INTO #A FROM A
SELECT * from #A
```

Currently I get output of 1000 row(s) affected.
But I need the output of the SELECT clause instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include

`SET NOCOUNT ON`

before entire script